# Creating LLM chatbot using llama-index + langchain

Tags: machine-learning, python, transformer, gpt, huggingface

As the title suggests: I'm trying to build a chatbot which his goal should be sort of like "chatgpt".

The chatbot will be installed on Slack workspace and I'm struggling with **which scope** I should create the documents on for building the index.

At the moment the document scope is "**per channel**" (i.e. **every channel is a whole document**), but I'm not sure it's the right approach (maybe it should be far **smaller** - does it make any difference at all?)

I'm also using huggingface transformers library, but since I'm newbie to this whole new evolving technology, I'm not sure what **type of model should I use**:

1. text2text
2. text-generation
3. summarization
4. quiestion-answering

I want the bot to address all (maybe I'm a bit naive).

... so overall, 2 questions:

1. What should the Document scope be?
2. Which type of model should I look at? Any specific recommended one?

Comment: Can you explain the usecase of the chatbot you are building so I could help you?